# Windows Service not starting due to DataAdapter.Fill()

Tags: c#, windows-services, sqldataadapter

I wrote a windows service that takes data from a local database and performs a function. To connect to the database I wrote the following code

```
SqlConnection connstring1;
            string conn1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nameOfConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            connstring1 = new SqlConnection(conn1);
            connstring1.Open();
            string cmd = "Select [OrderId], [VendorId], [txtPaymentMethod] , [txtPaymentStatus], [Updated_On] FROM [Postmate_ Shopping].[dbo].[tbl_Order_Master]  WHERE [txtPaymentMethod] = 'online' AND [txtPaymentStatus]= 'pending'";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, connstring1);
            da1.Fill(ds);
            da1.Dispose();
            connstring1.Close();
```

The code before da1.Fill(ds); is working and service gets installed but when da1.Fill(ds); is included in the code, service does not start.
I tried the same code in a web application and It was working fine.
This is what I get when da1.Fill(ds); is included:

***The "ScheduledService" service on Local Computer started and then  stopped.Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.***

To check if the service is working properly I removed the above code and replaced it with this code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"d:\ScheduledService.txt",
FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
//set up a streamwriter for adding text
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

//find the end of the underlying filestream
sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

//add the text
sw.WriteLine(content);
//add the text to the underlying filestream
sw.Flush();
//close the writer
sw.Close();
```

the service worked fine.
I tried searching for the problem but no relevant solution could be found.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Ask for clarity if needed.

EDIT:Any thoughts on using datareader?

Comment: Are you sure the connection string is correct, and that the query executes against that connection without errors?

Comment: Yes, the same code I tried in an web application and that worked fine.EDIT: It retreives the values from the database.

Comment: Do you use windows user to connecto to DB ?

Comment: I use Windows Authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because da1.Fill(ds) is the failing with an exception. Check the event log if there are any details of the exception. Looking at your code,
1) No need to open and close connection as the adaptor does that for you,
2) The dispose method should be after your close. 
3) Use "using" scope for your DB objects which will take care of the dispose implicitly.

Lastly, do not do this in the service start. The service start is really for any initialization and should return as soon as possible. Spawn a thread to perform any other activities.

Comment: To check the event log I went to **Event Viewer>>Windows Logs>>System**. I checked for entries under **Service Control Manager** and the following was in details:              **A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the Service1 service.**

Comment: And opening and closing connections and using dispose were desperate attempts to make the code work :P.

Comment: okie that clarifies that your sql code has exception. Try executing the code in a console app and make sure the connectivity works fine.

Comment: Yes I tried the same code in a web application and it was working properly.It was retrieving data.

Comment: okie, have you tried hardcoding the connectionstring? Is it a SQL authentication or windows?

Comment: Hardcoding the connection string?? hard coding which part? do you mean the string conn1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[**"nameOfConnectionString"**].ConnectionString.ToString(); ??

Comment: yes, at this point it either not reading your connectionstring properly or not authenticating. If it is a windows authentication, you have to configure the service to run under that user.

Comment: I will try that . Thanks

Comment: Can you suggest the changes that I will have to make?

Comment: go to service(control panel) -> right click on your service -> properties -> Logon tab, and provide the windows user and password.

Answer (score 0):

You said in comments that you use Windows Authentication, and your service is probably running under Local System account. Use SQL server authentichation or set service to run under your windows account.

Go to Services, then your Service properties and on tab Log On choose your windows user:

[image]

Comment: Okay I will try that. THanks

Comment: Can you suggest the changes that I will have to make?